# lose php session after javascript load on fb app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, session

I have strange issue. Some times work some time not.

New and clear application in page tab. First file start session and set some session parameter. second file only display this session var content. when i include second file in index it's work .. when call -  loadContent(second file) to same div i lose session.

In this situation strange is that this work in nights .. not id days :) 
I'm in Bulgaria GMT +3.

Here is my test [link](https://www.facebook.com/Tree.Frog.us/app_574637872635563)

2 files code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test_var']='this is test_var content!';
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function loadContent(page_index){
        $("#mpage").load(page_index);
        return false;
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadContent('fb-test_inc.php');">load via JS</a>
  <div id="mpage" style="border:1px solid red; padding:10px; margin:10px;">
  <? include ('fb-test_inc.php'); ?>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**fb-test_inc.php**

```
<? session_start();?>
<div style="border:1px solid green; padding:10px;">echo ($_SESSION['test_var']) = <?php echo ($_SESSION['test_var']);?><br />
var_dump($_SESSION['test_var']) = <?php var_dump($_SESSION['test_var']);?></div>
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Works fine for me … I see the same content after clicking the link as before. (And it actually has been updated, as I can see the response in Firebug.)

Comment: thanks for testing .. same code with any touch work for me too last night .. but now no .. i see NULL in var_dump :)
i wonder .. if now i visit different fb server .. how can i detect this?